# CAN we use JWT with CA signed cert

Tags: certificates, jwt

We have an inbound integration to salesforce where client uses JWT login mechanism. A self signed cert has been provided from salesforce which they use to sign the request. Is there any way we can use CA signed certificate instead of self signed cert?